# Is there a way to use the same jQuery Ajax for multiple items on a single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where people can add things to their "favorites" list with this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.doit-01234').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.domain.com/page.php?add=01234",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".result-01234").html('<span class="icon-favorite-green"></span>');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $(".result-01234").html('<span class="icon-favorite-red"></span>');
        },
        timeout: 15000
      });
    });
 });
```

The items get added with `page.php?add=01234`. The same page may however have 20 or 30 items that people can add to their favorites. Is there an easy way to use just one instance of this script for multiple IDs instead of the same jQuery code over and over after each item?

Meaning `page.php?add=9999` would then update `.result-9999` when `.doit-9999` is called and `page.php?add=5151` would update `.result-5151` and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your elements a common class and a custom data attribute:

```
<div class="ajax doit-01234" data-id="01234"></div>
```

And then use 1 handler:

```
$('.ajax').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/page.php?add=" + id,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        //Concatenate a selector based on the "id" in the data attribute
        $(".result-" + id).html('<span class="icon-favorite-green"></span>');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //Concatenate a selector based on the "id" in the data attribute
        $(".result-" + id).html('<span class="icon-favorite-red"></span>');
    },
    timeout: 15000
  });
});
```

Comment: `".ajax"` could also be `"div[class^='doit-']"`.

Answer (score 0):

Create this function like this:

```
  function Name (e) {
  var code =  01234;//extract your code like 1234 here by splitting or..
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/page.php?add=01234",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        $('.result-'+code).html('<span class="icon-favorite-green"></span>');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('.result-'+code).html('<span class="icon-favorite-red"></span>');
    },
    timeout: 15000
  });
});
```

Now where you want to call this function , you can call like this:
HTML:

```
<button onclick="Name(this);">Hello</button>
```